# PHP Safe mode is Off but mysql_connect still ignores username and password

Tags: php, mysql

Pretty much that. I am using PHP 5.4, I checked my server config and it says that safe mode is off I even tried checking it at runtime using ini_get and it was indeed off. But still, mysql_connect ignores my user and password arguments, I end up getting

> Failed to connect to database Access denied for user 'not_the_user_i_input'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

This is all the relevant code I guess:

```
$handle = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password) or die("Failed to connect to database: ".mysql_error());
$select = mysql_select_db($db_name, $handle) or die("Failed to select database: ".mysql_error());
```

Comment: The error suggests that your hostname is `localhost`, username is `not_the_user_i_input` and password is empty are these correct info?

Comment: I checked and all $db_ variables are correctly set. The problem is that mysql_connect is ignoring all my arguments, it is defaulting to the user I'm running as and no password as it usually does when safe mode is on.

Comment: Check in your `php.ini` if `sql.safe_mode` is set to 1 make it `Off` or remove it. And then restart apache.

Comment: Yes on the hostname, $db_username is set to a mysql username I created and granted privileges for this db and $db_password is set to its password, however not_the_user_i_input is different from that and apparently the password is being ignored.

Comment: Already checked and it is not. I even tried checking at runtime and it is indeed off.

Comment: Could your username/password contain control characters, tabs or newlines? Hardwire them as ordinary strings in the same file temporarily to ensure they are getting clean and normal strings.

Comment: Ok, apparently I fixed it but it's weird. So the code I showed was in a function contained in a file called db_manager.php which I intended to include in every other script that required to connect to the database. So the way I was trying to do this was including db_manager.php in a different file and calling connect(). Now I literally copied and pasted this code from that function into the new script instead of including db_manager and calling the function and it worked just fine. Any ideas why this happened?